# Core data entity array generate crash on release or remove objects in IOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsentitydescription

This is my `CoreDataManagerClass`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface RTC_CoreDataManager : NSObject
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
  - (void)saveContext;
  - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
  -(void)insertEntity:(NSString *)entityName arrayOfManagedObject:(NSMutableArray *)array;
  +(RTC_CoreDataManager *)shredInstance;
   @end

#import "RTC_CoreDataManager.h"
RTC_CoreDataManager *obj_RTC;
@implementation RTC_CoreDataManager

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

 - (void)saveContext
 {
 NSError *error = nil;
  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
 if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

           NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
           abort();
        }
   }
}

+(RTC_CoreDataManager *)shredInstance{
if (obj_RTC ==  nil) {
           obj_RTC = [[RTC_CoreDataManager alloc]init];
       }
        return obj_RTC;

    }
#pragma mark - Core Data stack


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
   if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
  }

   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
   if (coordinator != nil) {
       __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
       [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
   }
   return __managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"RTC" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
 {
     if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
   }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]     URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"RTC.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:storeURL toURL:[NSURL alloc] error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Oops, could copy preloaded data");
    }

__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

-(void)insertEntity:(NSString *)entityName arrayOfManagedObject:(NSMutableArray *)array 
{
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
for (id object in array)
 {

 [backgroundMOC performBlockAndWait:^
 {
 NSError *error;
 if (![__managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
 {
NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}];
}

}

@end
```

And this is my code in another controller.

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     appDele_Obj = (RTC_AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   appDele_Obj.entityArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{

    Survey *objSurvey = [NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Survey"
                         inManagedObjectContext:[RTC_CoreDataManager shredInstance].managedObjectContext];        [objSurvey setFirstName:@"1"];
    [objSurvey setLastName:@"2"];
    [objSurvey setEmpId:@"3"];
    [objSurvey setLanguage:@"Hindi"];
    [objSurvey setCountry:@"India"];
    [objSurvey setSurveyNo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    [[appDele_Obj entityArray] addObject:objSurvey];
    [objSurvey release];
}
//[objSurvey release];
[[RTC_CoreDataManager shredInstance] insertEntity:@"Survey" arrayOfManagedObject:[appDele_Obj entityArray]];
if ([[appDele_Obj entityArray]count]  >0) {
    [[appDele_Obj entityArray] removeAllObjects];

}
}
```

So My question is,
If I call method removeAllObjects on `[appDele_Obj entityArray]` crashing the application. Why I can not call `[[appDele_Obj entityArray] removeAllObjects];`
in above approach. Any one can help me to solve this crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple case of memory mis-management. This creates an autoreleased object:

```
Survey *objSurvey = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Survey"
    inManagedObjectContext:[RTC_CoreDataManager shredInstance].managedObjectContext];
```

Then you do this:

```
[[appDele_Obj entityArray] addObject:objSurvey];
[objSurvey release];
```

You should not be calling `release` here. The object is autoreleased-- calling `release` is not only unnecessary, it's dangerous. Later on when you remove the objects from the array, you end up over-releasing every object in it. That causes the crash.

A few other things from the code:

1. Calling `save:` on a managed object context in a loop is unnecessary unless you're making new changes on each pass through the loop. Your `insertEntity:arrayOfManagedObject:` method is doing a lot of unnecessary work.
2. The array in `viewDidLoad` is not necessary or useful for what you're doing. You've created the objects, and they're in the managed object context. Once you finish setting the attributes of those objects, you don't need to keep references. Keep adding objects until you're done, then tell the managed object context to save.
3. It's a minor detail, but you named a method that creates a singleton `shredInstance`. "Shred" is almost exactly the opposite of what you're doing in that method. You probably meant `sharedInstance`.